# Sort char array using sort function c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates, char

I am trying to limit user input into alphabet only, then sort all the character in ascending order.

build messages
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string::basic_string(char&)'

This is my header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <regex>
```

should i convert the char into string then convert back to char for my following code ?

```
string Sortstr (str[mlength]);
sort(Sortstr.begin(), Sortstr.end());
```

getting this 2 line error.

```
int mlength = 100;
int main() {
    char str[mlength];
    int length;

    cout << "Please enter a c-string: ";
    cin.getline(str,mlength,'\n');
    regex pass1("^[a-zA-Z]+");
    while(!regex_match(str,pass1)) {
         cout<<"Error"<<endl;
         cout << "Please enter a c-string: ";
         cin.getline(str,mlength,'\n');
    }
    string Sortstr (str);
    sort(str, str + strlen(str));
}
```

Comment: `string Sortstr (str[mlength]);` is undefined behavior, due to indexing the array out of bounds, not to mention, that it is non-standard C++ to use VLAs )variable length arrays) in the first place (`mlength` is not `constexpr`).

Comment: Why are you using a `char` array to begin with instead of a `std::string`?

Comment: `string Sortstr (str[mlength]);` ==> `string Sortstr(str);`. And you are using non-standard VLAs in C++. Avoid that, and just use a `std::string` and `std::getline` properly.

Comment: Also not that [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not really a part of C++, though some compilers have it as a non-portable extension.

Comment: my idea is sorting user input into ascending order for example , bcda / dcba /cdba into abcd then start my permutation (arrange it into all possible combination) and the output will always sort start from A-Z

Comment: lets say user input dcba ,  set length into 2 , instead of DC DB DA CA and ....... it will always start from AB AC AD .......

Comment: @qing: Avoid to edit question in a way which invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just sort `str`?

```
sort(str, str + strlen(str));
```

There's no reason you can't sort an array directly. Just pass pointers to the first and one-past-the-end elements of your array to `sort`. In this case adding `strlen` gets a pointer to the effective end of your array.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks, fixed now, I didn't look at the original code closely enough.

Comment: changing the      sort(Sortstr.begin(), Sortstr.end()); into    sort(str, str + strlen(str));

Comment: the function will sort ACbdD  into ACDbd instead of AbdCD , why the lowercase not in the front

Comment: it work  fine if all input are the same all in lowercase / uppercase

Comment: @qing because that is the order defined by the character set you are using. If you want a different order you must write a comparison function that gives you the order you want and pass it as the third parameter to `std::sort`

Comment: @qing But that's a different question so ask a new question if you are having trouble with that (or google changing the order of a sort is a very common thing to do)

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
string Sortstr (str[mlength]);
```

you are using the index operator on a char array which gives you one single char. So, you are passing one single char to the string constructor. This constructor does not exist, hence the error. Even if it existed, you do not want to pass one single char but the entire char array.

What you want is this:

```
string Sortstr (str);
```